# array of vectors c++ add edit remove search

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

I want to write a program for a bunch of users (not specific number of them) that each have contact details which contains username, phone number and email(all strings) , so I need three columns(const);

```
vector<string>info[3];
```

So my question is how can I add and remove rows(each user is one row) to this or search and edit them? 
search[I want each row to have a number and search them by that number]

Comment: for the number add an ID column

Comment: `struct UserInfo { std::string _userName; std::string _phoneNumber; std::string _email; }; std::vector<UserInfo>;` And look up `std::vector::push_back`/`std::vector::emplace_back`, `std::vector::erase`, and `std::find_if`.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for someone to write code for you. Please check out how to ask questions on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should at least show some effort - and code - and precisely tell us where you're struggling.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to c++, and this was my first question here I've coded parts of it and what I'm struggling with is the whole array of vectors and vectors of arrays or whatever and how they work. thnQ though

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you created class that is designed to manage single user info.

Nonetheless you can still store either vectorinfo[3] or objects of the class mentioned before in standard containers like:

- `std::map` or
- `std::list` or
- `std::array` or even
- `std::vector`

Which one of them?

It depends strictly on what you are going to do with those
   information. You can read about every of standard containers in
   documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the email is unique, use a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) where each `key` is an email and `value` is a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or array storing the username and phone number

Maps are typically implemented as binary search trees. So, time complexity of searching for an element (key) is `Log(N)`

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
...

std::map<std::string /* email */, std::vector<std::string>> users;
```